# How do I add dynamic filters to a Cypher query using the JS driver?

Tags: javascript, neo4j

Is it possible to use query params as dynamic filters? Consider the following function:

```
const propFilter = (session, prop, filter) => session.run(`
  MATCH (a:Animal)
  WHERE a.{prop} = {filter}
  RETURN a
`, {prop, filter})
```

Ideally it would be a a general purpose property filter. For example:

```
propFilter(session, 'name', 'Milo') // {name: 'Milo', species: 'Dog'...}
// runs this query
MATCH (a:Animal)
  WHERE a.name = 'Milo'
  RETURN a


propFilter(session, 'age', 27) // {age: 27, species: 'Elephant'...}
// runs this query
MATCH (a:Animal)
  WHERE a.age = 27
  RETURN a
```

Basically I want the driver to intelligently sub the params in to the `WHERE` clause, preserving the types of params (for example, it knows `'Milo'` is a string in the first query, and `27` is a number in the second.

I also want to avoid string interpolation inside the query:

```
// bad, but does what I want
(session, prop, value) => session.run(`
  MATCH
 (a:Animal {${prop}: {value}})
  RETURN a
`, { value })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
const propFilter = (session, prop, filter) => session.run(`
  MATCH (a:Animal)
  WHERE a[{prop}] = {filter}
  RETURN a
`, {prop: prop, filter: filter})
```